1-fragments of the Naive Set Theory with independent self-membership of the main set
I'm doing some research in non-trivial fragments of Naive Set Theory ($\mathsf{NST}$). By fragment of $\mathsf{NST}$ I mean that some instances of unrestricted comprehension (UC) are left out. UC is for me the following schema:
$\exists y\forall x(x\in y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$ s.t. $y$ is not free in $\varphi$.
The base fragment $\forall\mathsf{CL{+}ext}$ is then just the classical predicate logic with $=$-axioms and the axiom of extensionality.
In particular, I'm now investigating so-called 1-fragments of $\mathsf{NST}$ with just one instance of UC. In given 1-fragment, let us call the set defined through the property $\varphi$ (of the instance of UC), the main set.
In this question, I would be interest in some examples of 1-fragments s.t. the self-membership of the main set is independent in the given 1-fragment.
So far, I have the following examples:

base + $\exists\{x:x \in x\}$
base + $\exists\{x: x \text{ "contains exactly one elem"}\}$ (also "two elems", "three elems" etc. -- it could also be mixed like "one elem or three elems")

1) My first question would be: What are some other examples?
2) My second question would be: Is there some notion of "finite set" s.t. in base + $\exists\{x: x \text{ "is finite" (using that notion)}\}$, the self-membership of the main set is independent?

Since the first question is too open-ended and an answer to the second question also provides an example as required by the first question, I’ll just answer the second question here:
As it turns out, both “usual” notions of finiteness, namely in bijection with a natural number and Dedekind finiteness (there is no bijection between the set and a proper subset) work, as long as you phrase them correctly. Let’s begin with the first one:
Definition (in the base fragment of NST): $A$ is called an inductive set if,

The empty set, should it exist, is an element of $A$;
For any $x \in A$, if $x \cup \{x\}$ exists, then $x \cup \{x\} \in A$.

$n$ is called a natural number if for all inductive set $A$, we have $n \in A$. For two sets $A, B$, a bijection from $A$ to $B$ is a set $f$ s.t.,

For each $a \in A$, there exists a unique $b \in B$ s.t. the ordered pair $(a, b) := \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ exists and is in $f$;
Conversely, for each $b \in B$, there exists a unique $a \in A$ s.t. the ordered pair $(a, b)$ exists and is in $f$.

$A$ is called finite if there exists a natural number $n$ and a bijection $f$ from $n$ to $A$.
Now, I claim that in $\mathcal{T} = $ “base of NST + $\exists\{x: x \text{ “is finite”}\}$”, whether the set $\{x: x \text{ “is finite”}\}$ contains itself is independent. Indeed, we first consider the model of $\mathcal{T}$ with just one object $a$ satisfying $a = \{a\}$. Then checking the definition, as $a \cup \{a\} = a \in a$, we see that $a$ is an inductive set, so it is also a natural number. Since $(a, a) = \{\{a\}, \{a, a\}\} = a$, you can check that $a$ is a bijection from $a$ to itself, whence it is finite. So $\{x: x \text{ “is finite”}\} = a$, which contains itself.
Now, consider another model of $\mathcal{T}$ with two objects $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$, where $\varnothing$ is, of course, the empty set. It is not hard to check that there is no inductive set, so both $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are natural numbers. $\varnothing$ is a bijection from $\varnothing$ to itself, so it is finite, but it is not hard to check there is no bijection from either $\varnothing$ or $\{\varnothing\}$, to $\{\varnothing\}$, as $(\varnothing, \varnothing) = \{\{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \varnothing\}\} = \{\{\varnothing\}\}$ does not exist. Thus, $\{x: x \text{ “is finite”}\} = \{\varnothing\}$, which exists and does not contain itself.
Now, for the Dedekind finiteness version:
Definition (in the base fragment of NST): $A$ is called Dedekind infinite if there exists $B$ and $f$ s.t.,

$B$ is a subset of $A$, i.e., for all $b \in B$, we have $b \in A$;
$B \neq A$;
$f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

$A$ is called Dedekind finite if it is not Dedekind infinite.
Now, I claim that in $\mathcal{T} = $ “base of NST + $\exists\{x: x \text{ “is Dedekind finite”}\}$”, whether the set $\{x: x \text{ “is Dedekind finite”}\}$ contains itself is independent. Indeed, in the structure with a single object $a = \{a\}$, you can again verify that $a$ is Dedekind finite (which is quite straightforward this time - there doesn’t exist any $B$ s.t. $B \neq a$, so the second condition in the definition of Dedekind infiniteness can never be satisfied). So again $\{x: x \text{ “is Dedekind finite”}\} = a$ contains itself.
To prove that it is consistent that $\{x: x \text{ “is Dedekind finite”}\}$ does not contain itself, the two elements model no longer works. Instead, working in ZFC, then $V_{\omega + 1}$, the collection of all sets whose elements are all hereditarily finite sets, is a model of $\mathcal{T}$ in which no set contains itself. It is a model of $T$ because for any hereditarily finite $a, b$, $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ is hereditarily finite, so for any set $A \in V_{\omega + 1}$, any bijection from $A$ to a subset of $A$ must be an element of $V_{\omega + 1}$. Since in ZFC, being infinite and being Dedekind infinite are equivalent, we have, in $V_{\omega + 1}$, the Dedekind finite sets (relative to $V_{\omega + 1}$) are exactly all the hereditarily finite sets. Since $V_\omega$, the collection of all hereditarily finite sets, is an element of $V_{\omega + 1}$, this proves the desired result.

that is a nice answer. of course, these notions of finite are not perfect in a sense that there are some structures where they do not work as wanted. nonetheless, I don't even know whether such perfect notion of finite exists. so thank you very much.
